Does FIDE allow viewing how many IM/GM norms a player has?
I'm interested in seeing the norms of a certain player.
Is there a way to see through the FIDE website? Going to the player's profile doesn't seem to help. Also for players with titles already how do I know where the norms are obtained.


Is there a way to see through the FIDE website?

Only for players who have not yet achieved all the norms they need. You can go to this web page, select the title (IM or GM), select the country of the player and see the list of players from that country with outstanding norms. You can then click on the player's name to see what norms they have.
For example, I can see from this page that the English player Borna Derakhshani has two IM norms. I guess you could try shortcutting the process by copying the URL and replacing the player id and title to fit your needs.

is the other way around also possible. lets say for example a player a like Gukesh. also i think the list has anomalies. i can see simon williams in the GM list

I m too interested n curious from very long not only about the norms but also if there's anyway to still make into chess from India , I don't know from where to start officially, more importantly how even to start playing officially, do I need to register to fide first ???

Brian Towers' answer covers the part for viewing norms for players who are yet to obtain the title.
To view the norms of a player who has already got a title will have the follow the steps
Example take D. Gukesh

Go to fide profile https://ratings.fide.com/profile/46616543
Go to the bottom and you will see which FIDE PB/Congress the title got approved. Here it says Grandmaster    1st quarter PB 2019, 4-6 March, Astana, KAZ
Go to https://ratings.fide.com/title_applications.phtml
From the dropdown select 1st quarter PB 2019, 4-6 March, Astana, KAZ https://ratings.fide.com/title_applications.phtml?pb=55
Now you will see all the titles that got approved there
Click on Gukesh's name and you will see all the norms and where they were obtained https://ratings.fide.com/title_applications.phtml?details=1&id=46616543&title=GM&pb=55&reff=0

